# __eq__ method for class that ignores some attributes

Tags: python, class, methods

This is my class:

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self, book1, book2, book3):
        self._book1 = book1
        self._book2 = book2
        self._book3 = book3

    def__eq__:?????
```

I need to create an `__eq__` method that checks if two `Test` classes are equal only when the `book1` and `book2` inputs are equal. `book3` input can be different and the classes would still be equal.

```
test1 = Test()
test2 = Test()
```

So I want to have `test1 == test2` be true after adding the 3 parameters above only if `book1` and `book2` are the same.

Comment: Vandalizing your own questions is contrary to the TOS for the site. You grant copyright when you ask it here; see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209436/self-vandalism-what-is-correct-action.

Comment: Please don't make more work for people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is untested, but something like:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return (self._book1, self._book2) == (other._book1, other._book2)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: in python 2, you have to implement `__ne__` as well else you can have surprises